# Predicates about functions in 1st order logic

Tags: functions, notation, first-order-logic

Given the usual definition of function as a subset of $ D \times C $. What is the correct way to write "All functions $ f $ from $ D $ to $ C $ have property $P(f)$".  This is both a question about notation but also can I make statements like this safely without my logic becoming second order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you mean in the first order language of set theory, involving the single predicate "$\in$". You need to be able to talk about unordered pairs, ordered pairs using the definition $\{u,\{u,v\}\}$, notions derived from these, and more.

To express "all functions $f$ from $D$ to $C$ have property $P(f)$", first we need to be able to express "$f$ is a function from $D$ to $C$". This requires being able to talk about ordered pairs. It's helpful to define a couple of predicates. First, 
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{IsOrderedPair}(p) := \exists x\,\exists y\, (p = \{x, \{x,y\}\}.
\end{align}$$
As a convenience, let's define a notation for the ordered pair of $x$ and $y$:
$$
\langle x,y\rangle := \{x, \{x,y\}\}.
$$
One more predicate definition:
$$
\operatorname{IsSecond}(p,y) := \exists x \,(p = \langle x,y\rangle).
$$
(It turns out that we don't need an $\operatorname{isFirst}$ predicate.)

Now we can define 
$$
IsFunction(f,D,C) := \forall p\,(p\in f\to \\ [\, \operatorname{IsOrderedPair}(p) \\
\land \forall x\,(x\in D \leftrightarrow \exists y\, \langle x,y\rangle\in f)\\
\land \forall y\,(\operatorname{IsSecond}(p,y)\to y\in C ) \\
\land \forall x,y,z\, (\langle x,y\rangle\in f\land \langle x,z\rangle\in f\to y=z)
\, ])
$$

Finally, the phrase in your question can be symbolized as follows:
$$
\forall f\,[\operatorname{IsFunction}(f,D , C) \to P(f)]
$$

Comment: Oops, forgot the "$f$ is single-valued" clause -- it was getting unwieldy and I just wanted to be done with it :) Fixed.

Comment: Oh, and "domain of $f$ is $D$", which I combined with the former clause to give what's now the biconditional $\leftrightarrow$. So it turns out $IsFirst$ isn't needed at all, and I got rid of it.